# Is it possible to specify an automatic configuration proxy in web.config?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I'd like the server web.config configuration to match the client as closely as possible. All clients use a [proxy auto-configuration script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config).

Is there any way to specify this script file in web.config?

Comment: Can you give some detail on this "proxy auto-configuration script"?

Comment: @John: Added link to answer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config

Comment: thanks. Now you have to explain why a server should use the same Internet Proxy as the clients. For instance, are they located in the same area? Also, I'm not sure that a proxy is relevant to a server if all it will be doing is accepting incoming connections.

Comment: @John: On the latter point, there is server side ASP.NET code grabbing an RSS feed and processing it before delivering to the client. On the former, I understand your point. At this stage this is an isolated dev environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes

Directly under `<configuration>`:

```
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
      <proxy scriptLocation="--- your script location here ---" bypassonlocal="True" />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

Comment: bypassonlocal="True" is not always a good idea according to this article: [why-scriptlocation-may-not-work-when-pointing-to-a-proxy-script-file-in-your-application-config-file](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickrain/archive/2011/03/25/why-scriptlocation-may-not-work-when-pointing-to-a-proxy-script-file-in-your-application-config-file.aspx)